# Change Websphere8.5 port to 8080

Tags: websphere

I set up a Webshpere 8.5 by following the guide, then I went to “Servers”, “Server Types”, “WebSphere application servers”, “server1”, “Ports”. Changed “WC_defaulthost” to “8080”.

I also went to “Environment”, “Virtual Hosts”, “Default Host”, ”Host Aliases”. Changed the first entry from “9080” to become “8080”.

Then I deployed a project to it, I would like to access it via http://{my IP}:8080/{my app name}, but it never works, and I cannot find any error in C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1\SystemOut.log, in fact I can find a log entry in it saying "Application started: {my app name}".

Another log entry is "Web Module {my module name} has been bound to default_host[*:8080,*:80,*:9443,*:5060,*:5061,*:443]."

I also run "netstat -an" via command line, cannot find any record about port "8080"

Comment: Did you restart WAS after the change?

Comment: yes, I restarted it several times after the change

Comment: Check the SystemOut.log, server starts correctly (the open for ebusiness message). Also at the end of the log you should have entries similar to this `[11/4/14 17:20:41:285 CET] 00000001 TCPChannel    I   TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_2 is listening on host *  (IPv4) port 8080.
[11/4/14 17:20:41:285 CET] 00000001 WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundDefault.` . And if start was successfful it should be in netstat like this `TCP  0.0.0.0:8080  0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you seeing in your browser (404, 500, etc...)?

You probably won't see much in the log unless you have web container trace on. A very useful thing to enable at first is the HTTP inbound channel's NCSA access and HTTP error logging. This would produce a log similar to what you will find in web servers that log the client requests and the response given to them.

If you can't find this request in the log, then it means that it simply hasn't reached the server in the first place. At that point you want to check the network. A very common issue is a firewall blocking the port.